# How to add extra column to query result

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'd like to add one extra column with same text "Toys" to query result.

in the Cell G2, I want the query to be like this:

​
" select *, 'Toys' label 'Toys' 'Product Type' "

This is the expected result I want to display:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13ZsgJwCkWwLLAok1GD0OtFin0I4kfbAU-f_pysVhEAY/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: select one `Toys` cell and push it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to list all the columns explicitly for that. `SELECT *, 'toys'` construction does not work in Google Sheets `QUERY()`.

```
=QUERY(A1:B8,"SELECT A, B, 'Toys' label 'Toys' 'Product Type'")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
=QUERY(A1:C11,"label A 'Items', B 'Price', C 'Product Type' ")
```

*(**Adjust** the formula according to your ranges and locale)*